# How to calculate the maximum Torque for a PMSM Motor?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, pmsm

I have a cheap BLDC/PMSM Motor from Ebay. I don't have any further Information, only a sticker: "A2212/10T 1400KV".

I connected my oscilloscope to 2 phases of the motor and I have seen that the Back EMF is sinusoidal, so I think its a PMSM.

Then I made the following measurement, for 10 Hz rotation speed the Back EMF was `800 mV Pk-Pk` and `71 Hz` Freq.

So I calculated \$Kq = \frac{Vpk-pk}{4\times π \times \sqrt 3 \times Freqbemf}  = 5.228\times 10^{-4}\$

and

\$pole pairs = \frac{(60 \times Freqbemf )}{RPM} = \frac{71}{10} = 7.1 ~= 7\$

Is this correct?

How can I calculate max torque, psim?

Comment: You can get the torque constant directly from the voltage constant (which is stated in non-SI units as 1400 rpm/V)

Comment: @user_1818839 do you have the equation?

Comment: In SI units, Kv (volts/radian/sec) and Kt (Nm/amp) are identical.